# Create Chart using Reactjs Chartjs and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

Hi I am using Reactjs with Chartjs to create a Dynamic Charts

I receive an error when I plot the json data from api response. Chart component renders when I add hardcoded data like label ["a","b","c"] and data [3424,34324,34234] but doesn't render when i use load the data from api response.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import Chart from './components/Chart';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      chartData:{}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getChartData();
  }

  getChartData() {
    axios.get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/coXIyroYAy?indent=2").then(res => {
        const coin = res.data;
        let labels = [];
        let data = [];
        coin.forEach(element => {
        labels.push(element.labels);
        data.push(element.data);

          });

       console.log(coin)
        this.setState({
          chartData: {
            labels:labels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Population",
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
                ],
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      });
    }

  render(){

        return (
          <div className="App">
          {Object.keys(this.state.chartData).length &&
            <Chart
              chartData={this.state.chartData}
              location="Massachusetts"
              legendPosition="bottom"
            />
          }
          </div>
        );

    }     
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two adjustments in your code.

#### 1. Load data in `componentDidMount`

Change this line

```
componentWillMount = () => this.getChartData();
```

to

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getChartData();
}
```

You need to load the data once the component is mounted on the DOM.

#### 2. Render only when you have chart data

Conditionally render `Chart` component.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.keys(this.state.chartData).length &&
        <Chart
          chartData={this.state.chartData}
          location="Massachusetts"
          legendPosition="bottom"
        />
       }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should render your `Chart` only after `chartData` is populated from API response.

Comment: Probably it might have something to do with `backgroundColor` having only 3 entries while the api give 5 entries.

Comment: no i have array into array how i can fix that like it not work labels: Array(1)
0: Array(5)
0: "a"
1: "a"
2: "a"
3: "a"
4: "a"

Comment: and like it work labels: Array(6)
0: "a"
1: "a"
2: "a"
3: "a"
4: "a"
5: " a"

Answer (score 0):

it's work 
my mistakes in json `enter code here`

```
 getChartData() {
    axios.get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cghIWRNGEO?indent=2").then(res => {
        const coin = res.data;
        let labels = coin.chartData.labels;
        let data = coin.chartData.datasets.data;
        // console.log(data.Object.values(data)[0])
        // data.forEach(element => {
        // data.push(element.data);
        //   });

        this.setState({
          chartData: {
            labels:labels,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Population",
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
                ],
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      });
    }
```